# Calling "guess" variable for two objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm creating a game for homework, and I'm very stuck in the beginning stages. The game takes inputs from two players. The player class controls the guesses by each player. I've been able to correctly set up the player class so that it only accepts the allowed range of inputs.

However, I'm having difficulty calling the guess variable for two player objects. I've tried to determine how to call the value of each guess variable for each object, but it keeps giving me errors. Am I calling the variable correctly? Or is my logic of having two different guesses values for each player object correct? Or is there another way that I need to write the code to have a guess variable for each player?

player class code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class player {

//handles the input from the player
public player() {

      while (true) {

      // Prompt the user to guess the number
     System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(guess);

          if (guess < 0) {
              System.out.println("You entered a negative number. 
              + "The number you enter must be between 0 and 4. " +
                                 "Please try again. ");
          }
          else if (guess >= 5){
              System.out.println("You entered is greater than 4. "
              + "The number you enter must be between 0 and 4. " +
                      "Please try again. ");
          }
          else{
              break;
          }

        } // End of while loop

   }//end of player method

}//End of player class
```

Main code:

```
   public class HW2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("It's Player A's turn to guess!");
    player playerA = new player();  
    System.out.println(playerA.guess);


    System.out.println("It's Player B's turn to guess!");
    player playerB = new player();
    System.out.println(playerB.guess);

  }//end of main


} // end of HW2 class
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Food for thought: Your while loop seems redundant if you are only performing one guess!

Comment: You can't "call a variable". What does that even mean?

Comment: Several issues here: what are the players trying to guess? are they supposed to alternate turns? You cannot access guess because that is a private variable in the method (which is actually a constructor), you have to declare the variable public at the class level to access it directly. Other option, which is general convention, declare the variable private and then have a public method called getGuess which will only return the guess variable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your guess variable as an instance field instead of a method variable. It's simply a matter of scope

```
public class player {
    int guess;
    .....
```

and instead of `int guess = input.nextInt();`in the method simply write `guess = input.nextInt();`

This should solve the call issue

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the guess variable outside of its scope (this variable is only accesible in the player method).

In order to fix it, define a public field in the Player class and assign the guess value to it (better use setter and getter). Then you will be able to access it in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your initial question, about accessing the "guess" variable for each player:

The guess variable for each player is a local variable declared within the constructor. As such, it can't be seen outside the constructor scope and so when your main method tries to access `playerB.guess`, the compiler can see that there is no variable called guess in the player class. It doesn't, and can't, realize that you're actually trying to access a local variable inside the constructor. So, to solve this particular problem - you could make the guess variable a field in the player class. e.g.

```
//handles the input from the player
public player() {
    public int guess = 0;

      while (true) {

      // Prompt the user to guess the number
     System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    guess = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(guess);

          if (guess < 0) {
              System.out.println("You entered a negative number. 
              + "The number you enter must be between 0 and 4. " +
                                 "Please try again. ");
          }
          else if (guess >= 5){
              System.out.println("You entered is greater than 4. "
              + "The number you enter must be between 0 and 4. " +
                      "Please try again. ");
          }
          else{
              break;
          }

        } // End of while loop

   }//end of player method

}//End of player class
```

This will resolve the particular compile problem - but one thing to note, because the logic for making a guess is in the constructor of the player object, this means it will only be called once, when the class is created.